# Passing data to Controller failing (Tuple being used)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page which displays fields from 2 different models. To ensure this works I am using Tuple<> to display them both and have tested to ensure data shows which it does. The issue I had was when I submitted the form to update the database, nothing was passed and the record was wiped clean. Please advise me on how to proceed. I have shortened fields shown to make the post shorter.

### View

```
@model Tuple<CommunityParkletDashboard.Models.COMMUNITY_PARKLET_APPLICATION, CommunityParkletDashboard.ViewModels.CPDashboardModel>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CPDashboard", "CPDashboard")'" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditCP", "CPDashboard", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        Reference Number:
        @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.Item1.REF_NUMBER)
    </p>
    <p>
        Name:
        @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.Item1.NAME)
    </p>
    <p>
        Notes:
        @Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.Item1.NOTES)
    </p>
    foreach (var item in Model.Item2.lParkletApplicationDtos)
    {
        <p>
            Title:
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.ParkletTitle)
        </p>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCP(COMMUNITY_PARKLET_APPLICATION cpa, int id)
    {
        _context.UpdateParkletApplication(cpa, id);
        return RedirectToAction("CPDashboard");
    }
```

UpdateParkletApplication() is just a method which runs some SQL script to update the data using the model and ID so associate the record with, all this was working fine before I introduced second model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple` to generate form controls and have it bind (a `Tuple` has no parameterless constructor). As always, use a view model to represent what you want in the view.

Comment: In my case I have concatenated properties from the model to present them cleaner in the ViewModel. That is why I am using the original model to update a few fields. I did not know I could update my db using a ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

As your view contains model as

```
@model MyCustomModel
```

Following method should like this and then access cpa.Item1 just you did in view.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCP(MyCustomModel cpa, int id)
    {
        _context.UpdateParkletApplication(cpa, id);
        return RedirectToAction("CPDashboard");
    }
```

Your Model Class

```
public class MyCustomModel
{
    public CommunityParkletDashboard.Models.COMMUNITY_PARKLET_APPLICATION Item1  {get;set;}
    public CommunityParkletDashboard.ViewModels.CPDashboardModel Item2 {get;set;}
}
```

Ultimately you have to think like how is model constructed. Even if in View you keep Tuple then you can use above answer.

Comment: That cannot work - a `Tuple` does not have a parameterless constructor, therefore the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize it.

Comment: It seems that this is the answer you are looking for. If so then please accept this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create one form and use foreach form item2 it pass all item in item2.
You can use foreach and inside of it use begin form .

```
foreach (var item in Model.Item2.lParkletApplicationDtos)
        {
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditCP", "CPDashboard", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>
            Reference Number:
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.Item1.REF_NUMBER)
        </p>
        <p>
            Name:
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.Item1.NAME)
        </p>
        <p>
            Notes:
            @Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.Item1.NOTES)
        </p>

            <p>
                Title:
                @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.ParkletTitle)
            </p>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        }
    }
```

Does it pass id ???

@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.ParkletTitle)

Comment: No it does not pass ID, that part is simply for displaying data